# .InvalidOperationException in Process.start

Tags: c#-4.0, system.diagnostics

I have the following code

```
foreach (Items it in sortedList)
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    startInfo.FileName = it.filePath;
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    try
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = startInfo;
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch(Exception ew)
    {
        // Log error.
    }             
}
```

Every time I open a mp4 file I get an

> InvalidOperationException

and it says that there is no program linked to this format, but at the same time the windows media player starts up and shows the file.

Can someone explain to me why this code is throwing the `InvalidOperationException` and also how I can fix the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: you're running a process for each item in your list. Are you sure all the items has good format and can be played in media player. Also check the file path - it should contain double quotes if there is a space in your path.

Comment: The problem is the path of the executable, when I give it a full path of the executable the process is created correctly and everything works.